# How Can I Use External Component In My App?

Tags: react-native

I like to know that can I have two react-native apps and share components in these two apps??
is it possible to import components from other apps or address it in the current app??

I need to have some theme in my app and I like to handle it outside of the app.
for example, I have a dashboard in the web and I want to handle the app theme in it.

I think I should lazy load the theme components so my app doesn't get slow on runtime but I don't know the correct way.

I hope that my explanation is well enough to understand my request.

Comment: basically you want to customise your component through props and the props values may differ for different apps controlled through an api? correct me if I am wrong but if that's what you want. you can get json object through api and use that object to customise your component. You may still have default values for those props for initial render if you make the api call optional.

Comment: @WaheedAkhter thank you for thinking about it but if i have a component that get behavior with json my component is so big to render and i don't like that so i like to have seprate components in some where out of my app and when i need it call it.

Answer (score 0):

For common component, use should create an package by `npm` or other package management tools. Then you can import that component to any app.

Another way is apply [monorepo](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/doc/design/monorepo.md) approach by using [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna).

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a theme into your app but its to slow when you start it up - try to implement a nice loadingscreen where something animates and load the theme in the meantime so the user doesnt have to stare at an empty screen. This makes a good user experience because the user has something to watch while waiting.

Comment: no this is not my answer
i am looking for that how to load a component or them from an other app or website
but thank you for answering :)